# Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to create a generic helper function that does some processing. One of its inputs will be a function returning an array of something.

I can't figure out how to do this. I keep getting a compile error. I found the post

[argument for generic parameter could not be inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381490/argument-for-generic-parameter-could-not-be-inferred)

and tried adding `...as [String]` or `... as [Int]`, etc. but no luck.

```
func helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing<T>(displayedStrings: () -> [T])  -> [String]! {
    let listOfSomething: [T] = displayedStrings()
    // do something with listOfSomething
    return ["some", "resulting", "string", "from", "the", "input"]
}

func concreteFunction1() -> [AnyObject]! {
    var s: [String] = helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing {  // ERROR: Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.
        var str = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    } // tried 'as [String]' here

    // do something with s
    return s
}

func concreteFunction2() -> [AnyObject]! {
    var s: [Int] = helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing {  // ERROR: Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.
        var i = [1, 2, 3]
    } // tried 'as [Int]' here

    // do something with s
    return s
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  This is pretty confusing without more detail about what exactly sort of processing you're trying to do... because it seems a bit like an XY problem maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `return` appropriately and explicitly declaring the concrete type of `() -> [T]` solve the errors ... but I'm not sure it will get you what you want. Anyway here's the code:

```
func helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing<T>(displayedStrings: () -> [T])  -> [String]! {
    let listOfSomething: [T] = displayedStrings()
    // do something with listOfSomething
    return ["some", "resulting", "string", "from", "the", "input"]
}

func concreteFunction1() -> [AnyObject]! {
    var s: [String]! = helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing {
        () -> [String] in // Explicit declared type
        var str = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        return str
    } // tried 'as [String]' here

    // do something with s
    return s
}

func concreteFunction2() -> [AnyObject]! {
    var s: [String]! = helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing {
        () -> [Int] in // Explicit declared type
        var i = [1, 2, 3]
        return i
    } // tried 'as [Int]' here

    // do something with s
    return s
}
```

Notice I also corrected the type of `var s` since your generic function always returns an implicitly unwrapped optional array of strings `[String]!`. The return type is not generalised (i.e.: `T` or `[T]` etc.).

Probably you might need to change some type declarations in order to achieve your design needs.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

hi your closure body does no return

```
func concreteFunction1() -> [AnyObject]! {
    let s: [String] = helperThatDoesSomeGenericProcessing {  // ERROR: Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.
    return ["One", "Two", "Three"]
} // tried 'as [String]' here

    // do something with s
    return s
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't appear to fix the problem. I still get the same error.